# recorrer un array y retornar valor a botones

Tags: javascript, html

me he dado la cabeza contra un muro al intentar hacer esto, ya que no logre encontrar una solucion ni niguna pregunta similar en este sitio.

este es mi html hasta el momento:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Idle clicker II</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/OqjBtlqnXrYMbqWiApqPd2Gf2Rgij6bqmxn_RMgzmNldxzxrPuC9wFWrqXcCNU1_9g=w128">
</head>

<body>
    <table class="fixed">
        <tr>
            <td id="a">doaskdok</td>
            <td id="b"><button>buy amount</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="maintr">
        <tr id="spacer"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c">lvl</td>
            <td colspan="2" id="d">progress</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="e">lvl progress</td>
            <td id="f"><button>buy x</button></td>
            <td id="g">time</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

lo que yo quiero lograr con javascript es que, al presionar el boton de buy amount,  este recorra un array `amount=['1', '5', '10', '100', 'max']` y que al llegar a 'max' este vuelva a '1'

luego quiero que el numero seleccionado quede plasmado en el texto de los botones, AMBOS. (menciono esto ya que he tenido problemas con el `document.getElementsByClass`

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas, y no duden en preguntar aquello que no se entienda.

no he pegado ningunas lineas de js ya que todo lo que he probado no ha dado resultado.

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieras también las lineas de Javascript con las que has probado ya que así te podríamos dar respuestas más acordes a lo que le faltaba a tu script.

Comment: Revertí tu edición, la respuesta no va en la pregunta si no en la zona de respuestas justo debajo

Comment: Las respuestas van como tal, no como edición a la pregunta :D Mira en la parte inferior de esta página y agrega la respuesta.

Comment: explica mejor esto " y que al llegar a 'max' este vuelva a '1' " Con gusto te ayudaré.. recuerda que existen varios metodos para recorrer arreglos .map
.filter
foreach
forin etc

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí correctamente la situación que planeas, una posibilidad es añadir un id a ambos botones y hacer referencia a la función que se quiere ejecutar directamente desde el elemento del botón en la DOM:

```js
const amountArr=['1', '5', '10', '100', 'max'];
let i = 0;

function buyAmount() {
  let amount = amountArr[i],
      msg = "buy " + amount;
  document.getElementById("buyAmount").innerHTML = msg;
  document.getElementById("buyX").innerHTML = msg;
  i = ++i%5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Idle clicker II</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="fixed">
        <tr>
            <td id="a">doaskdok</td>
            <td id="b"><button id="buyAmount" onclick="buyAmount()">buy amount</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="maintr">
        <tr id="spacer"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c">lvl</td>
            <td colspan="2" id="d">progress</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="e">lvl progress</td>
            <td id="f"><button id="buyX">buy x</button></td>
            <td id="g">time</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

He logrado resolver esto de la siguiente manera:

```
function BuyMultiplier(a) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("BuyM").length;
    jAmount += a;
    if (jAmount >= BAlength) {
        jAmount = 0;
    }
    rAmount = Bamount[jAmount];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("BuyM")[i].innerHTML = 'buy x ' + rAmount;
    }
}
```

esta función en conjunto con este array:

```
var Bamount = [1, 5, 10, 100, max];
```

Gracias a todos! perdón por no responder antes. intente publicar mi solución hace unos días pero no se publico correctamente, por lo tanto la estoy publicando de vuelta